# MediaMetadataRetriever - getFrameAt - DOMX Error

Tags: android, widevine

MediaMetadataRetriever returns bitmap (as Standalone app, so we can assume there are no problems with video encoding) **but results in error while playing alongside drm protected content (Widevine)** (i.e) encrypted content will play and retrieval of bitmaps happens in background,

**Error in brief:**

```
05-09 11:56:06.751: D/DOMX(129): ERROR: non-secure component not supported in secure mode
05-09 11:56:06.767: E/SoftAVC(129): Decoder failed: -2
05-09 11:56:06.767: E/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001, -1007)
```

**Error Logs:**

```
05-09 11:56:06.751: D/DOH(21330): Extraction starts... 4011
05-09 11:56:06.751: D/DOMX(129): ERROR: non-secure component not supported in secure mode
05-09 11:56:06.751: I/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] AVC profile = 100 (High), level = 41
05-09 11:56:06.751: I/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] video dimensions are 320 x 240
05-09 11:56:06.751: I/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Crop rect is 320 x 240 @ (0, 0)
05-09 11:56:06.767: E/SoftAVC(129): Decoder failed: -2
05-09 11:56:06.767: E/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001, -1007)
05-09 11:56:06.774: D/DOMX(129): ERROR: non-secure component not supported in secure mode
05-09 11:56:06.774: D/DOMX(129): ERROR: non-secure component not supported in secure mode
05-09 11:56:06.774: I/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] AVC profile = 100 (High), level = 41
05-09 11:56:06.774: I/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] video dimensions are 320 x 240
05-09 11:56:06.774: I/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] Crop rect is 320 x 240 @ (0, 0)
05-09 11:56:06.790: E/SoftAVC(129): Decoder failed: -2
05-09 11:56:06.790: E/OMXCodec(129): [OMX.google.h264.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001, -1007)
05-09 11:56:06.790: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(129): failed to capture a video frame
05-09 11:56:06.790: E/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI(21330): getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL pointer
```

Would really appreciate if any one can point me towards resolving this?
Any info/docs for this error would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever?

Comment: Unfortunately, due to licensing FFmpeg cannot be considered.